# Laravel Route Failed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a little problem.
When I connect to the site: mysite.com/uebersicht, I get this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Controller method not found.
```

My Routes:

```
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
Route::controller('uebersicht', 'UebersichtController');
```

UebersichtController

```
<?php

class UebersichtController extends BaseController {
    public $layout = 'master';

    public function getIndex() {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('uebersicht.index');
        $this->layout->title = 'Server &Uuml;bersicht';
    }

}
```

The HomeController works, but the UebersichtController not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `/ controller` at the bottom.

Try the following:

```
Route::controller('uebersicht', 'UebersichtController');
Route::controller('/', 'HomeController');
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of the routes so '/' is last.